# Fail2ban only works with log files?

Tags: fail2ban, ipc

What about Unix sockets? I have created my own server application that needs protection.

My two options:

- Creating a log file for fail2ban to watch
- Establish networking between my server application and fail2ban (Unix sockets)

Comment: Doesn't your application [already log](https://12factor.net/logs)?

Comment: Not yet; it's in early stages of development. However, it will - and fail2ban will be able to watch it. My question relates to why limit fail2ban only to log files. There could definitely be a standardized net protocol.

Comment: fail2ban can also read the systemd journal. So logfiles are not strictly necessary.

Comment: the log is standard, bsd, unix, windows, etc.. it was done to be easy to adapt to is my guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fail2ban` does **not** monitor unix sockets; it only works with logfiles. The rationale probably are:

- logging is easy: you can not only log on a custom file, but also tap into syslog/journal with very little effort;
- plain text logs are very handy when you are creating/verifying custom fail2ban regex/rules;
- unix sockets can be used for a moltitude of communication protocol, while a plain log file is very "direct" about its content and format rules;
- finally, in the *nix word logging **is** mostly done with standard text files. Why deviating from such (good!) behavior?